# Servlet is not loading index.hml

Tags: java, servlets

I have created simple servlet which displays "Hello World" on accessing desired URL but I can't get it to load as index.html which looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/test/say_hi" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

web.xml looks like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>app.version</param-name>
    <param-value>1.0.000</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>app.properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/usr/local/tomcat/default/myapp/configInfo.properties</param-value>
</context-param>   

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        480
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.my.app.testService.ServiceContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Tomcat is set to open browser as `http://localhost:8080/test` and artifact application context deployment for `test.war` set as `/test`. After deploying it throws `404 Not Found` for `http://localhost:8080/test` request where I expect server will load `index.html`

When I access it manually as `http://localhost:8080/test/say_hi` it works.

What I have done wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message (or the precise diagnostic)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta `404 Not Found` for `http://localhost:8080/test` request where I expect server will load `index.html`

Comment: Where is installed the index.html file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta in the `webapp` folder and when is exploded is in the `test` folder